# How do I create a pivot table from a dataframe that has a column contains lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and it looks like,

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "binary_vote": 0,
    "genres": [
      "Adventure",
      "Comedy"
    ]
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "binary_vote": 1,
    "genres": [
      "Adventure",
      "Drama"
    ]
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "binary_vote": 0,
    "genres": [
      "Comedy",
      "Drama"
    ]
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "binary_vote": 1,
    "genres": [
      "Adventure",
      "Drama"
    ]
  },
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

   userId  binary_vote               genres
0  1       0            [Adventure, Comedy]
1  1       1            [Adventure, Drama]
2  2       0            [Comedy, Drama]
3  2       1            [Adventure, Drama]
```

I want to create column from `binary_vote`. And here is the expected output,

```
   userId        binary_vote_0       binary_vote_1
0  1       [Adventure, Comedy]  [Adventure, Drama]
1  2       [Comedy, Drama]      [Adventure, Drama]
```

I tried something like this, but I get an error,

```py
pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['binary_vote'], values='genres')
```

Here is error,

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to create our own `aggfunc`, in this case it's a simple one.

The reason it failed is because it tried to take the `mean` as it's the default aggregation function. Obviously, this will fail on your list.

```
piv = (
    df.pivot_table(index='userId', columns='binary_vote', values='genres', aggfunc=lambda x: x)
      .add_prefix('binary_vote_')
      .reset_index()
      .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
print(piv)
```

```
   userId        binary_vote_0       binary_vote_1
0       1  [Adventure, Comedy]  [Adventure, Drama]
1       2      [Comedy, Drama]  [Adventure, Drama]
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. How can I drop `binary_vote`column? I tried `df.drop('binary_vote', axis=1)` but I got error like this: `KeyError: "['binary_vote'] not found in axis"`.

Comment: See edit with `rename_axis`, `binary_vote` is not a column, its the `name` of your column index.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `set_index()` and `unstack()`:

```
m=(df.set_index(['userId','binary_vote']).unstack()
     .add_prefix('binary_vote_').droplevel(level=0,axis=1))
m.reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1)
```

---

```
   userId        binary_vote_0       binary_vote_1
0       1  [Adventure, Comedy]  [Adventure, Drama]
1       2      [Comedy, Drama]  [Adventure, Drama]
```